# ACORD XML Namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces

We are developing web services for the insurance domain & we are using the ACORD XML schemas as the standard. The web service is generating the ACORD XMLs with namespace as the following:

```
<ns:TXLife><ns:Party></ns:Party></ns:TXLife>
```

If the namespaces are included in the ACORD XMLs, is it considered ACORD XML? What is the advantage of using namespaces in the ACORD XMLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the namespaces are included in the ACORD XMLs, is it considered ACORD XML?

If the XML conforms to the ACORD XML schema (i.e., the namespaces and arrangement of the elements are correct, required elements are provided, etc.), then the XML is "ACORD XML."

Your XML example that you provide needs to define the prefix `ns` to refer to the appropriate ACORD namespace name that you are using. I assume it's in your full XML somewhere since you're working with an auto-generated web service -- but if not, it needs to be added.

> What is the advantage of using namespaces in the ACORD XMLs?

Without the ACORD namespace, the XML cannot be considered ACORD XML. Note that the namespace doesn't necessarily *make* the XML into ACORD XML because it still must conform to the ACORD XML schema.

Answer (score 0):

If these elements are defined in a standard schema, then they *must* be in the correct namespace.